# variable doesn't get value from for loop

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart, variables

Why is the Value of `Response response` not getting the value from the inner for loops response? Its value stays `""`

```
Future getArticle() async {
  final data1 = await fetchArticles();
  Response response = Response("", 200);
  for (int i = 0; i == data1.length; i++) {
    response = await get(
      Uri.parse('https:/url/' +
          data1[i]["file"]),
    );
    return response; //I want it to have this responses value
  }

  String data2 = (response.body);
  return data2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop you post is like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i == data1.length; i++) {
    response = await get(
      Uri.parse('https:/url/' +
          data1[i]["file"]),
    );
```

This won't trigger the i++ at all, since you are checking if i == data1.length.
Change it to i < data1.length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        response = await get(
          Uri.parse('https:/url/' +
              data1[i]["file"]),
        );
```

This will make sure it fully loops through the entire length of data1.

Answer (score 1):

This loop doesn't make sense. It will always return the first element and exit the loop in which case you don't need a loop. If you want a loop then do this:

```
data1.forEach((value) => {
    response = await get(
      Uri.parse('https:/url/' +
          value["file"]),
    );
    return response.body;
});
```